# Can someone explain what kind structure does this variable have?

Tags: php

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($all_events); $i++) {

    $temp_event = $this->model_events->find_event($all_events[$i]['event_id']);
    $data['attending_events'][$i]['event_id'] = $temp_event[0]['event_id'];
    //return everything from the ticket table based on the event id
    $ticket_data = $this->model_tickets->get_ticket_owner($data['attending_events'][$i]['event_id']);
    for($j = 0; $j < count($ticket_data); $j++) {
        $data['attending_events'][$i]['tickets'][$j] = $ticket_data[$j];
    }
        $data['attending_events'][$i]['e_name'] = $temp_event[0]['e_name'];
        $data['attending_events'][$i]['e_date'] = $temp_event[0]['e_date'];
        $data['attending_events'][$i]['e_price'] = $temp_event[0]['e_pricetemp'];
        $data['attending_events'][$i]['e_is_address_hide'] = $temp_event[0]['e_is_address_hide'];
}
```

I'm new to php, I'm getting really confused by the variable structure. As you can see in the code above, there is a variable called `$data`. This is the variable that I don't understand.

First of all, in `$data['attending_events']`, is `attending_events` an index, just like array[0], or something else?

And what is the number `$i` in `$data['attending_events'][$i]['e_price']`.

Finally what is this `'$data['attending_events'][$i]['tickets'][$j]'`? Is this another layer?

I'm fimiliar with C++. This is `$data` variable something like a multidimentional vector?

Comment: `print_r($data);` <-- See for yourself

Comment: It's a multidimensional array

Comment: @RamRaider How many dimensions does it have? Is it 4?

Comment: Remember, arrays in PHP can be associative (with string keys like `'attending_events'`), or numeric, or a mixture of both. And multi-dimensional arrays can have either type nested inside. This is because PHP is loosely-typed.

Comment: *"How many dimensions does it have?"* - What Rizier123 said..

Comment: @IanDrake Thank you for the interpretation. This is exactly what I'm confusing about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $data is a multidimensional array. As Rizier123 told you, do a `print_r($data)`, and in the browser, use the "View page source" command to see the whole hierarchy correctly indented.

If you need more info on each element (like the type), use `var_dump($data)`.

If you are familiar with C++, you may be concerned about how it is allocated, how many dimensions it does have and so on. However, it's totally dynamic. You can create new elements and dimensions just by setting values, like this:

`$data['attending_events'][$i]['tickets'][$j][1]['another dimension']['yet another one'] = 10;`

Comment: and.. to make it more confusing still, each level/leaf could itself be a multidimensional array if the devleoper was a total sadist / masochist

Comment: Thank you Marcovecchio. This is exactly the answer I want! I don't know you can create new dimensions and elements whenever you want to. Again, thanks so much!

Comment: @MingAn, glad to help! If you think it properly answered the question, please mark it as the correct one!